# Update MariaDB column when provided value is not empty string

Tags: mysql, sql, go, mariadb

I am currently working on a Golang application that talks to a MariaDB database. My service will take in a `*User` and attempt to update the matching record.

For example:

```
func (d *database) UpdateUser(user *User) error {
    stmt, err := d.Prepare(`UPDATE Users
        SET FirstName=?, LastName=?, Email=?, Address1=?, Address2=?,
            City=?, State=?, Country=?, PostalCode=?
        WHERE Id=?`)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err := res, err := stmt.Exec(user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.Email,
        user.Address1, user.Address2, user.City, user.State, user.Country, 
        user.PostalCode, user.Id)
    return err
}
```

However, I do not want to update fields that aren't supplied. I am looking for something closer to this, where it would not update the value if the provided one is an empty string:

```
`UPDATE Users
 SET FirstName=? OR FirstName, LastName=? OR LastName, Email=? OR Email, 
     Address1=? OR Address1, Address2=? OR Address2, City=? OR City, 
     State=? OR State, Country=? OR Country, PostalCode=? OR PostalCode
 WHERE Id=?`
```

I have seen that SQL allows for updating using a `CASE` statement, but I do not see a way to use this without providing the same variable to the `Exec()` several times.

Comment: Does "not supplied" come in as the empty string, or as `NULL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
UPDATE Users
SET FirstName = case when ? is null then FirstName else ? end
```

or to pass each parameter just once

```
UPDATE Users
SET FirstName = coalesce(?, FirstName)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to pass in the same variable twice in a row?

Comment: Is that my only option?

Comment: No, I found another one

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'll accept your answer when it allows me in a few minutes.

Comment: I thought I read MariaDB recognizes empty string as null, but I was wrong. Since empty string is not `NULL`, `COALESCE()` is choosing the empty string.

Comment: I ended up using the first example and passing in each variable twice in a row. However, it would be better if I could only supply each variable once.

Comment: The clean solution would be to make sure the DB gets NULL instead of empty strings.

Comment: Is there an easy way for that to be done? I am just Unmarshalling JSON into a struct and passing it in to the method to be updated. Even if the JSON has a null value, it gets set to empty string when the struct is created.

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert in JSON.